# stopwatch - stop and start

Tags: swift, stopwatch

I am working on a simple stopwatch. 
The problem that I face is to start/resume stopwatch where I left off when I start again.
I tried to keep the value of elapsed time, but no luck

demo = 
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var timer:Timer = Timer()
    var time:Int = 0
    var isActive: Bool = false
    var isReset: Bool = true
    var startTime:TimeInterval?
    var elapsed:TimeInterval?

    var timeInterval:TimeInterval?

    var laps:[String] = [String]()
    var timerDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var lapTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopwatchLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!



    @IBAction func addLapAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if isActive {
            addLapToTableView()
        } else {
            resetTimer()
        }
    }



    @IBAction func startWatchButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if isActive {
          stopTimer()
        } else {
          startTimer()
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
        configureTableView()

        startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

    }

    func configureTableView() {
        lapTableView.delegate = self
        lapTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    //start timer
    func startTimer() {
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.incrementTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        isActive = true

        startButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        labButton.setTitle("Lap", for: .normal)

    }

    func funcTimer() {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.incrementTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    //stop timer
    func stopTimer() {

        isActive = false
        isReset = false


        timer.invalidate()

        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        labButton.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
    }

    //reset timer
    func resetTimer() {

        isActive = false
        isReset = true

        laps = []
        lapTableView.reloadData()
        stopwatchLabel.text = "00:00:00"
    }

    func incrementTimer() {
        time += 1

        if isReset {
            stopwatchLabel.text = newTime()
        } else {
           stopwatchLabel.text = updateTime()
        }

    }


    //add lap to tableView
    func addLapToTableView() {
        laps.append(stopwatchLabel.text!)
        lapTableView.reloadData()
        print("current lap : \(stopwatchLabel.text!)")
    }


    func displayMinSeconds(time:Int) -> String {

        let minutes:Int = time / 60 % 60
        let seconds:Int = time % 60
        let milliseconds:Int = time * 1000

        return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i",  minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
    }


    func newTime() -> String  {
        let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        let elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime!
        return updateTimer(time: elapsedTime)
    }

    func updateTime() -> String {

        return updateTimer(time: elapsed!)
    }

    func updateTimer(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        var elapsedTime = time

        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.

        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime  / 60.0)
        elapsedTime  -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.

        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime )

        elapsedTime  -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.

        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime  * 100)

        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants


        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

        elapsed = elapsedTime
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d",  minutes, seconds, fraction)

    }



    //MARK - Table View Data Source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return laps.count
    }


    @objc(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lapCell", for: indexPath)


         cell.textLabel?.text = "lap \(indexPath.row + 1)"

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = laps[indexPath.row]
        }



        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: About your image: "This page isn’t working".

Comment: It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is playing with both an incremented variable to display the time, and Date() references to calculate the differences. This is really tricky to accomplish, and having built a few timer apps before i can tell you that sticking to either approach is much better than adopting both ways.

The method I strongly recommend is the incremented variable, that runs a timer every 0.01 seconds (since that's the highest decimal point you're displaying), with your time variable being how many 0.01 seconds have elapsed. That way, when you stop/resume, you're just re-adding to that value, displaying the elapsed time becomes a simple math problem along with accessing that time in minutes/seconds/hours etc. 
Personally, I prefer this method over using Date() because you have more freedom around how you can display information, you dont need to rely on property type conversion from Date() properties and either way, for simple use cases, you will have to store a number-type value somewhere even when you do use Date(). So you might as well not bother using Date() at all for simpler timer apps.

The only time Date seems to be more usefull, is when you need persistency (saving on file or in a database). As in when you want a timer that can be dismissed, and brought back where you left off, when you're monitoring time spent with location data and when you want time data that might be used later for activity analysis, or user trends etc.

The simplest case i can think of for you that uses Date would be to play around with the timeIntervalSince1970 property of Date. It also doesn't calculate things when you pause it, saving on battery consumption just like an incrementing approach. You still need a time incrementer variable to keep track of time spent recording, and another variable to keep track of time spent while paused, but it can help if you're trying to use both numbers and Date

```
var start = Date()
var stopped : Date?
var resumed : Date?
var finished : Date?

var timer : Timer?

var timeElapsed = Double()
var timeStopped = Double()

var actualTimeElapsedInMilliseconds : Int {
    get {
        return Int(timeElapsed - timeStopped)
    }
}

var actualTimeElapsedInTenthOfSecond : Int {
    get {
        return Int((timeElapsed - timeStopped) / 10.0)
    }
}

var actualTimeElapsedInSeconds : Int {
    get {
        return Int((timeElapsed - timeStopped) / 1000)
    }
}


func startTimer() {

    start = Date()
    timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { (this) in
        performActiveTimer()
    })

}

func reStartTimer() {

    resumed = Date()
    if let stop = stopped, let resume = resumed {
        timeStopped = timeStopped + (resume.timeIntervalSince1970 - stop.timeIntervalSince1970)
    }
    timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { (this) in
        performActiveTimer()
    })

}

func pause() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    stopped = Date()
}

func performActiveTimer() {
    timeElapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970
    //here i would call you UI update method
}

func terminateTimerAndSave() {
    let now = Date()
    finished = now
    timeElapsed = now.timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

As stated before, using an incrementer takes less code, but this hybrid method is the simplest way to do a timer. This is just the logic by the way, you'd need to use the computed variables shown to display the time in which ever way you would want. You also need to make sure you alternate methods properly. so as to avoid overriding the optional dates improperly.

Comment: If this helped out, let me know